# Is it possible to connect to a remote wifi, then share internet with that wifi?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, router, connection-sharing

I'm trying to do something that I've never done before, but it seems like it should be possible. I'm asking in general if this is possible, but I'll also give my system details in case something is too specific.

I have a MacBook Pro 2012 with a USB 3G Modem connected to the internet. I have an Airport Extreme that does not have internet. I have another computer on my network, connected to the Airport, that needs internet temporarily. Ideally, I'd like to connect my 3G modem to the internet, then use my wifi to connect to the Airport, thereby sharing my internet with that Airport AND the networked computed.

I know that OSX has an option to share my internet connection, but it sets up a wifi hotspot from my laptop. That doesn't work because (I'm pretty sure), my Airport Extreme can't go out and connect to my hotspot.

I also cannot connect the modem to the networked computer because it's a linux server that would need to be able to download drivers... Besides, I don't know enough about linux to be able to get it working.

So, is this possible?

Comment: Share the connection on your macbook, it will create a hotspot which is essentially an AP (access point). Then connect your airport to the hotspot in bridge mode. I don't know the exact steps but thats the general idea.

Comment: If that's an answer, why not post an answer below?

Comment: because, i don't know the exact steps and a moderator will probably delete it.

Comment: good point @BroScience

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link from Apple support, I think it could help you.

[OS X Lion: Share your Internet connection](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3853)

Comment: While it's unlikely this link will go offline, could you please include the most important steps here on-site? Even then, how does this solve the OP's problem? They know they can share their WiFi connection already but how exactly would that allow them to provide access for the other machine through the AirPort?